# Combine two list of decimals in one array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, xamarin, highcharts

I've got an issue that I am facing and I can't wrap my head around it for how I could solve this. I got two `List<decimals>` that contains really small values like 0.0567 and 4.67890 and so on. Then my second list is also `List<decimals>` and that contains epoch time stamps in milliseconds. Example: 1472100900000, 1472101200000, 1472101500000 et cetera. And with that kind of data I would like to make a list or an array that is like this. (i.e. `array[] : [[1472100900000, 0.0567], [1472101200000, 4.67890], [1472101500000, 3.568]]`) and so on. And then finally throw it in Highchart that it will make a nice graph.

This is what I already tried with linq, but the result is not what I want it to be, because the values are not set after each other.

```
var combi2 = timeArray.SelectMany(x1 => valueArray, (x1, x2) => new[] { x1, x2 });
var combi3 = valueArray.SelectMany(x1 => timeArray, (x1, x2) => new { x1, x2 }).Select(x3 => new PerformanceGraphData { PerformanceTime = x3.x2.ToString(), PerformanceValue = x3.x1.ToString() });
```

I hope that someone can help me with this. If there is need for more information please do not hesitate to ask.
Thank you for reading.

Kind regards,

Fernando

Comment: `Enumerable.Zip` method. or one can always use `for` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `Zip` extension method.

```
timeArray.Zip(valueArray, (x1,y1) => new decimal[] {x1,y1}).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Now I have a two dimensional array of decimals[][], do you know how I can l ToString the second array in the dimension?

Comment: Do you mean, you want output in `string[]` where each string represents `{x1,y1}`?

Answer (score 0):

Linq's Zip method is your way:

```
var graphData = timeArray.Zip(valueArray,
                        (x, y) => new PerformanceGraphData
                        {
                            PerformanceTime = x.ToString(),
                            PerformanceValue = y.ToString()
                        }).ToArray();
```

[Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two
>   sequences, producing a sequence of the results.